# Control Flow in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to print out a result based on 2 variables. I have an array 8 elements long...

- If any element in that array is less than 40, I want the result to be loser. The rest of the conditions can be skipped.
- If all elements are above 40, then I want to start checking the value of `a`, which is calculated separately. If a is between certain values then it prints out the result.

I've tried breaking out of multiple loops but when I run the program, sometimems depending on input im getting "Loser" and "Decent" printed out together, when I expect only one of the two.

```
  outerloop:
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if (module[i] < 40 ) 
        {
            System.out.println("Loser");
        } 
        else 
        {
                if (a >= 0 && a < 40) 
                {
                System.out.println("Loser");
                } 
                else if (a >= 40 && a < 60) 
                {
                System.out.println("Decent");
                } 
                else if (a >= 60) 
                {
                System.out.println("Leet");
                }

        }
        break outerloop;

    }
```

Comment: The way the code is currently written, with only a single loop, you will always break after the first iteration. Move the break into the if condition. Also, since you're only using a single for loop in this sample you don't need to use a label, just a simple break will get out of the loop.

Comment: This question seems better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @atk I disagree. This code here doesn't work as it is planned to. Therefore, it belongs here.

Answer (score 2):

You can't check them within the same loop easily.  I'd break it up.  Off the top of my head:

```
boolean loser = false;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length && !loser; i++) {
    if (module[i] < 40 || a < 40)  {
        System.out.println("Loser");
        loser = true;
    }
}

if (!loser) {
    if (a >= 40 && a < 60)  {
        System.out.println("Decent");
    }
    else if (a >= 60) {
        System.out.println("Leet");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use labels for control flow.  Instead, put the functionality into a separate method.

Java is not meant to be used like [Fortran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran) or [Basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC) which use `goto`'s to move to various points in a program, which is typically written in a single scope.  Like this:

```
function(){

     section1: if(condition) goto section2

     section2: if(condition) goto sectionN
     ....
     sectionN: if(condition) goto section1      
}
```

Java is typically organized more like

```
java.exe:Main{

    Class(){
         classRelatedMethod(){
            Class(){ ... // recursive definition }
         }
    }
}
```

This allow each `class` to define reusable, discrete pieces of functionality that are coupled to each other.  Where they are not, a new `class` should be defined.  While many other languages (including Fortran and BASIC) can accomplish this, Java was designed from the ground up with this in mind (along with being a platform independent language as well, but that's not *quite* the same thing.)

All of this is pretty academic and can be found with Google pretty easily.

Comment: Ive been learning for 3 weeks mate, but thanks for the put down

Comment: Sorry, it sounded like a student fishing for someone to write his code for him, which I won't do.  At some point, people have to work these things out for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You've got quite a problem here: an array of values which you want to 'score' as a group.

If any value is < 40, you want to stop looking and print 'loser'.

If the current value is >= 40, you need to keep looking because the next value might be < 40;

however, you also want to know if there is a 'leet' score somewhere in the array.

So:

```
boolean loser = false, leet = false;
for( int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i ) {
    if( array[i] < 40 ) {
        loser = true;
        break;
    }
    // if it's not < 40, it must be more
    // now check if it qualifies as leet
    if( array[i] > 60 ) {
        leet = true;
    }
}
if( loser ) {
    print loser
} else if( leet ) {
    print leet
} else {
    print decent
}
```